# Different Segments may collapse with each other

Tags: assembly, x86-16

When we code, then we give different segment registers the same value, in that case the two different segments may mess up with each other, and the problems may arise. 
For example in below given condition.

```
MOV AX, CS
MOV SS, AX
ASSUME SS: DOSGROUP
```

as mentioned in above lines, in line 1 we move CS to AX. Immediately after it we AX to SS. This means at this point CS and SS registers are containing the same value or same memory location, Is'nt that true that when we code further, the contents of CS will collapse with the contents SS.

Comment: What do you mean by "collapse"?

Comment: The CPU will allow it. It's up to you to make sure the code and the stack stay distinct, and the stack writing commands (PUSH, CALL) won't overwrite the code. There's 64 KB of space in the segment - if the stack stays in the low offsets and the code is loaded to the high offsets (e. g. CS:8000), it might work.

Comment: How can we perform two operations (e.g. one for CS and another for SS) using same memory location. And there in this situation, I mentioned collapse.

Comment: There is no problem with it whatsoever. Whenever it needs to access memory the cpu will perform the address mapping using whichever segment is specified in the instruction. The fact that multiple segment registers may point to the same segment is irrelevant. It's your job to manage memory usage so you don't accidentally overwrite stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the segment registers won't change the content of the memory (in fact in real mode memory is not accessed at all), it will only change the *CPU's view of memory* (the logical to linear translation).

Having two segment registers with the same value only means that the same offset *X* can be used with both to access the same data.
This is handy if we don't want to instruct the assembler on how to count the offset for different segments.
If we write an assembly program naively, we'll lack the segment information for the assembler which will consider our program a single code segment. Thus the assembler will use the same offset counter for *both* data and code but at runtime these two area are accesses with different segment (namely `DS` and `CS`) unless you override it for every load/store.
If the property of above were not true, the data offsets generated by the assembler won't match were the loader loaded the program.

This is also useful when taking pointer to functions or handling data on the stack through a pointer (i.e. without a fixed offset from `bp`), it essentially transforms every pointer into a near pointer.
So the offset of a variable effectively becomes the address of a variable, without further need to also consider the segment. This makes address/offsets easier to reason about because now if a variable has offset `X` this is the only offset we have to be concerned about, `X` is the same whetever we use `CS`, `DS` or `SS`.
So `X` is 1-1 mapped to its var, if we had to take segments in consideration each var could have as much as 64Ki/16 offsets and this set is *not disjoint* from the offsets set of another variable (i.e. the offset `X` can denote two different variables, when used with two different segments) and so pointers had to be far.
Since we have only an handful of effectively free segment registers, far pointers (besides doubling the pointer size) put a lot of pressure on the registers allocation strategy.

Of course, putting all the code, data and stack into one segment may be challenging due to the relatively small size of a segment (64KiB).
Code and data are not usually set up by the programmer (their layout is fixed once the binary is built) so only the stack is set up, one must be careful not to set the stack pointer too close to the end of the data and of the code.
Proper handling of the stack can be often neglected by a back of napkin calculation on the max call chain depth, but if we can't bound our call chains or we have so much code/data that the stack size is in the hundred of bytes we probably need to refactor.
Managing the stack properly in real mode is hard due to a lack of features, I can't think of a method better than checking the stack pointer at each function entry.

Unless we have multiple segments per type of data (data/stack, code) using separate segments increase the addressable memory at no cost but a few lines at the initialisation (granted we don't take function pointers).
Having the same segment for the stack and the data is useful when passing pointers to structures on the stack.

DOS `.com` executables are an example of programs where `CS`, `DS` and `SS` all share the same value.
DOS `.exe` executables are often assembled/compiled for the small memory model, where we only have code (`CS`) and data (`DS`, `SS`) segments.
However they can handle other memory models, including the huge one where we can have multiple segments for type of data (code, stack, data).

Programming with multiple segment is error prone, that's why 32-bit OSes stopped using it and 64-bit OSes can't use it (but in a limited fashion).
However segments are also useful, they can create an handy view in memory, especially when accessing MMIO and the ISA regions.

This wall of text is hard to parse if you don't have sufficient (painful?) experience with segments, my advice is to start with a working program and intentionally hurt your self by moving data into (unnecessarily) separated segments.
Just keep in mind how logical addresses (segment:offset) are translated into linear addresses (segment * 16 + offset).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to split my answer into two parts.

**Part 1**

> This means at this point CS and SS registers are containing the same value or same memory location ...

In 16-bit x86 programs, segments do not describe memory locations but they describe **ranges** of memory locations:

An "idealized" 16-bit CPU can only work with 64 KiB of memory. To be able to work with more memory than 64 KiB, 8086-compatible CPUs have segments:

The value of a segment register describes the memory range of 64 KiB size where the CPU should work. So a 16-bit program can (only) access 64 KiB of memory, but by changing the value of the segment register, it can select which 64 KiB of 1 MiB memory shall be accessible. This means that a program can effectively access 1 MiB of memory (and not only 64 KiB) by changing the values of the segment registers.

Of course the code and different types of data may be located in the same 64 KiB memory range. (In the case of a computer with only 64 KiB of memory (such as a 1982 IBM PCjr) this is even obvious.)

In this case `CS` and `SS` have the same value because the code (`CS` register) and the stack (`SS` register) are located within the **same 64 KiB memory range**.

But there is a difference between "the same memory range" (which contains a lot of **different** memory locations) and "the same memory location".

**Part 2**

> How can we perform two operations ... using same memory location.

Let's change your example and use the pairs of registers `SS:SP` and `ES:DI` instead of the registers `CS` and `SS`. These pairs actually describe a memory location and not a memory range.

What happens if `SS:SP` and `ES:DI` have the same value?

Answer: Nothing.

The CPU uses `SS:SP` to calculate the memory location for stack operations (e.g. `push` or `pop`) and `ES:DI` for string write operations (e.g. `stos` or `movs`).

Because the CPU does not perform two operations at once, there is no problem if the same memory location is specified for both kinds of operations.

However, you have to take care that nothing stupid happens. Example:

```
push bx
; Let's say SS:SP and ES:DI contain the same value here
stosw
pop bx
```

Using the `stosw` instruction you would destroy the data you have `push`-ed using the `push` instruction because `SS:SP` and `ES:DI` point to the same memory location.

The CPU does not care about this. If the CPU is instructed to overwrite the stack, the CPU will overwrite the stack.

It is your task as programmer to avoid this.

But actually you have **exactly** the same problem with every programming language. In C, C++, C# or Java you could to the following mistake:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

... and not understand why the inner loop is executed 10 times instead of 50 times.